# How to permanently save settings of SQL * Editor?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

In Sql * Editor which is the default editor for Oracle 10g, when we change the settings like rownum,pagesize. The changes are only for current session. After we exit from SQL * Editor, all the settings get erased . Can we make the changes to be permanent ?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you mean SQL*Plus, then yes - you can use a personal `login.sql`, or a global `glogin.sql`, with a list of configuration statements. See [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_two.htm#i1132910) for details; not sure I can add anything useful to what that says. Make sure they are in the right place though:

> The Site Profile script is $ORACLE_HOME/sqlplus/admin/glogin.sql in
>   UNIX, and ORACLE_HOME\sqlplus\admin\glogin.sql in Windows.
>
> The User Profile script is generally named login.sql. SQL*Plus
>   searches for the User Profile in your current directory, and then the
>   directories you specify with the SQLPATH environment variable.
>   SQL*Plus searches this colon-separated list of directories and their
>   subdirectories in the order they are listed.

Additionally, I sometimes have sets of scripts which want similar formatting, but not necessarily what I'd want in an interactive session (like reports perhaps). For those I have a separate file with the relevant settings, and I include that at the top of each script with `@format.sql`, rather than having to add the whole list to each script file. Also makes it easier to make a change to all of them if it becomes necessary. That runs after the `login.sql` or `glogin.sql` so it sometimes needs to reverse things in those to get back to the default behaviour.

Comment: I edited the file as you said **glogin.sql** with command **SET LINESIZE 10**. After that I exited from SQL* Plus Editor. Then login to the SQL * editor, seems no changes. When I enter command **SHOW LINESIZE**, it is the same previous one. May be I am doing something wrong, same happened with the file **login.sql**. Any suggesstions ?

Comment: You put the files in the directories specified in the documentation?